# Combine Dataframes With Different Indexes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 : here index is ip

            accountname      name
ip
192.168.1.1        aaaa  john doe
192.168.1.2        bbbb  jane doe

df2 : index is accountname

             gsm
accountname
aaaa         850
bbbb         860
cccc         870
```

I have to combine two dataframe and add gsm column to df1.

```
            ip accountname      name  gsm
0  192.168.1.1        aaaa  john doe  850
1  192.168.1.2        bbbb  jane doe  860
```

These dataframes has different indexes and I couldnt reach right data. any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `merge` with `index` as well.

```
In [2313]: df1.merge(df2, left_on='accountname', right_index=True).reset_index()
Out[2313]:
            ip accountname      name  gsm
0  192.168.1.1        aaaa  john doe  850
1  192.168.1.2        bbbb  jane doe  860
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df1.join(df2, on='accountname', how='inner').reset_index()
print (df)
            ip accountname      name  gsm
0  192.168.1.1        aaaa  john doe  850
1  192.168.1.2        bbbb  jane doe  860
```

Comment: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'accountname'], dtype='object')

Comment: First or second solution?

Comment: first solution @jezrael

Comment: I think `df = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on='accountname')` should help.

Comment: Interesting, second solution does not work too?

Comment: @jezrael comment refers to the best solution. Can you post it as an answer? 
Please, do tag me so that I may know and upvote your answer. The comment is: 
df = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on='accountname')